# Is my solution correct for inverting the function $a/(n-b)$

Tags: functions

I inverted the following function:

$$r(n) = {a \over n-b}$$

Inverting the function:

$$r^{-1}(n) = { a + bn \over n}$$

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see. If your solution is correct, then $r(r^{-1}(n)) = n$ for all values of $n$ and $r^{-1}(r(n))=n$ for all values of $n$.

Well, $$r(r^{-1}(n)) = r\left(\frac{a+bn}{n}\right) = \frac{a}{\frac{a+bn}{n} - b} = \frac{an}{a+bn - bn} = \frac{an}{a} = n$$

So yes, it looks like you did it. You can check the other equaity yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s(m) = \frac{a + bm}{m}$.

Can you compute $s\circ r(n)$ and $r\circ s(m)$?